# Simple html layout

Tags: html, iframe

I need simple thing I guess. But I can't find or figure out how to do it. It look's simple but maybe it's not.

I need html page with header, 1 sidebar on left hand side and footer. Now the tricky part. I heed content right form sidebar to be fluid. In that area I need to place iframe. Page should not have any scrollbar so only scrollbars will be the ones inside iframe. I have problem that this area is always moved under bottom edge of the screen by height of header. This is because I use height 100% but I don't know any other method. If there is way to do height: 100%-120px it wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Can you mock up an image of what it should look like?

Comment: What do you have already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this Demo : [Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lCfAs)

**HTML Code**

```
<header>
  Header
</header>
<nav>
  Nav
</nav>
<div>
  <iframe src='http://sasidhar.com' width='100%' frameborder='0' height ='100%'>
</div>
```

**CSS Code**

```
* { padding : 0; margin : 0; }
header {
  position absolute;
  top : 0;
  height : 50px;
  background-color : #ccc;
}
nav {
  position : absolute;
  width : 200px;
  top : 50px;
  bottom : 0;
  background-color : #ece;
}
div {
  position : absolute;
  left : 200px;
  top : 50px;
  bottom : 0;
  right : 0;
  background-color : #cee;
  overflow : hidden;
}
```

Is this helpful? Let me know.